# I can't remove scroll sounds

Tags: sound, software-installation, scrolling

I have a sound when I scroll and I want to disable it.  I can't figure it out and I have been trying and trying. Running Linux Mint Cinnamon.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)